# Start the WOW animation.js without page reload

Tags: javascript, html

There's a problem I don't know how to solve. I did an animation of buttons appearing with WOW.js, but when I press the button I need the elements to disappear with the same animation. The concept is that when you press the button, the reverse animation starts, and then I hide the object using setInterval and display: 'none'. But I can't start manually so that when I press the button the animation starts againю

HTML

```
<div class="col-6">
<button class="answer-block wow fadeInLeft" id="firstAnswer">A</button>
</div>
<!-- /.col-6 -->
<div class="col-6">
<button class="answer-block wow fadeInRight" id="secondAnswer">B</button>
</div>
<!-- /.col-6 -->
</div>
<!-- /.row -->
```

JS

```
let firstAnswer = document.getElementById('firstAnswer');
let secondAnswer = document.getElementById('secondAnswer');

firstAnswer.onclick = function (){
    firstAnswer.classList.remove('fadeInLeft');
    secondAnswer.classList.remove('fadeInRight');

    firstAnswer.classList.add('fadeOutLeft');
    secondAnswer.classList.add('fadeOutRight');

}
```

Comment: it is not really clear what you are trying to achieve. In general you should save the state (hidden/shown) in a variable and onClick should change this state and do an animation based on new state.

Comment: I want to when you press the button triggered animation wow.js